# Flex: load parent class into module

Tags: apache-flex, module

My main application contains a `ClassA`. The main application then loads a module and in that module I would like would to do:

```
var classA:InterfaceClassA = new ClassA();
```

It compiles fine but I get this warning:

```
Warning: YourApplication is a module or application that is directly referenced. This will cause YourApplication and all of its dependencies to be linked in with module.YourModule:Module. Using an interface is the recommended practice to avoid this.
```

I can't use an interface to generate the new instance, so what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in [Accessing the parent application from the modules](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_7.html) . I created a helper class in the main Application that contains instances of the classes I want to access. In the module I then use:

```
parentApplication.myModuleHelper.**myClassInstance**.myMethod();
```

for instance methods and for static class level methods I use:

```
parentApplication.myModuleHelper.**MyClassInstance**.myMethod()
```

To get an instance of my class in a module I use this in MyModuleHelper

```
public function getFullScreenUtil(iFullScreenUtil:IFullScreenUtil , iSystemManager:ISystemManager):FullScreenUtil {
    return new FullScreenUtil(iFullScreenUtil , iSystemManager);
}
```

and this in MyModule:

```
var _fullScreenUtil:* = parentApplication.moduleHelper.getFullScreenUtil(this , systemManager);
```

which is all I need for now. I am not sure how I could cast the result of `getFullScreenUtil(..)` to an actual instance of `FullScreenUtil` but I expect that it can not be done in modules. Maybe using an interface would provide the solution to that.

Comment: Better than this should be the use of -link-report when compiling the main application, and then use -load-externs when compiling the module. This should have worked but for me it didn't. The Flex classes were excluded but my custom classes in the Application were not even though they were in the generated link-report.